# Bazel has a bug when handling protobuf files. How can I resolve this temporarly?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, bazel

I'm having an issue building my code base with Bazel, Go and Protobuf. The Protobuf files aren't mapped right by Bazel Gezelle when generated. I think it's a [known bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3867). I've opened up my [own ticket](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/issues/209). If this is the problem, I don't expect it to be resolved anytime soon. It was tagged as a P2 and has been open since October. I'm looking for a solution to the problem in the mean time.

We use a custom Protobuf [plugin](https://github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro) when buliding our protobuf files. My thought process is to generate the protobuf files by hand and have Bazel ignore the protobuf files, just using the already generated code.

Does this sound like something that would work? How would I do this? Can I have Gezelle ignore the Protobuf files for me?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Copying my reply on [bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#209](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/issues/209) for anyone running into the same issue.

---

Yep, [bazelbuild/bazel#3867](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3867) is the issue.

Whenever you build a `proto_library` with Bazel (for in any language, not just Go), Bazel thinks the imports are relative to a repository root (either in your local repository or in any of your external repositories). I'm guessing `brand.proto` is importing `github.com/xxx/jscode/jsge/pkg/paging/proto/page.proto`. Since the file you want to import is actually `jsge/pkg/paging/proto/page.proto`, protoc won't find it when invoked by Bazel.

Since this is an issue with `proto_library`, there's not much Gazelle or rules_go can do about it. If [bazelbuild/bazel#3867](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3867) is implemented, you'll be able to adjust `proto_library` import paths. Until then, you won't be able to build `proto_library` rules without modifying them.

Unfortunately, the best advice I can offer at the moment is to check in pre-generated .pb.go files and include those in your `go_library` rules. If you add a comment `# gazelle:proto disable` in your root build file, it will ignore .proto files and will include .pb.go files.